# hide #dialog ui , when clicked outside ,example checked. pls

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 2000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 500
      }
    });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

Comment: Spent a little time to search what you want. There are tons of this. This question have not a problem IMHO.

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question in order to receive a positive response on Stack Overflow. Just posting code with a project request is going to be looked upon very negatively in fact.  I believe your question is "how do you hide a jquery dialog when clicked outside of the dialog box." Can you confirm this? Or better, update your post?

Comment: yes, i understand my mistake, im novice in this , sorry ))and thanks

Answer (score 0):

define a id to the button for example,and do something like this

```
$("#id").click(function() {
 $("#dialog").hide();
});
```

Comment: You're missing an end quote (`"`).